# Retrieve full origin URL of postMessage event

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, postmessage

I am setting up a page that embeds different content via iFrames. Both the parent site and the iFrame content are communicating via the [Window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) API. In the parent site I am then listening to the events via `window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);`. Is there a way for me to know the exact origin of the events received? I know that every event contains an `origin`, but this is only the base URL of the embedded site (protocol, domain, port).

However, if I embed two iFrames with the same base URL but different paths, how can I know which of the two iFrames sent the message?

Comment: I don't think you can. The assumption is that you know which domains you trust, you don't need more fine-grained access control than that.

Comment: You can have them send their URL as part of the message.